Error -107 cannot open connection! (when I try to create shared folders)
I have a system made up of Windows 10 with Vmware Workstation 17 PRO and an Ubuntu 24.04 LTS virtual machine on it (kernel version : 6.8.0-41-generic). In order to share files between the host and Ubuntu, I have configured Vmware to allow this possibility. However, when I opened Ubuntu, the /mnt folder remained empty when, in principle, it should contain the /hgfs folder. I have manually created this folder and executed the following command:
/usr/bin/vmhgfs-fuse .host:/ /mnt/hgfs -o subtype=vmhgfs-fuse,allow_other.
And the answer has been:
Error -107 cannot open connection!
which, curiously, I have not been able to find anything on the web related to that error.
Otherwise, I have the latest version of Vmware-Tools installed (2:12.3.5-5build3) and all Ubuntu packages updated. What could be the problem?

Have you researched Vmware support for an answer?
